# Adobe Muse: SVG with graphic style and CSS disappears in chrome (but not in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, muse

[preview in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN2Pa.jpg)

[preview in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACBp5.jpg)

1. I added a svg image.
2. added graphic style named "imageHover" and applied on the image.
3. Inserted to image HTML between :

   ```
   <style>
   .imageHover {
     opacity: 0.8;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
     transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
     box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
     transition-duration: 0.3s;
     -webkit-transition-property: transform;
     transition-property: transform;
     -webkit-transitionorigin: center center;
     transform-origin: center center;
   }
   .imageHover:hover, .imageHover:focus, .imageHover:active {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
     transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
     opacity: 1;
   }
   </style>
   ```
4. File-> preview in browser -> image disappeared from page in Chrome, but works perfect in Firefox.

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Help us to help you. Please create an [MCVE] so we can see for ourselves the problem in action.

Comment: SVG images are not shown on Chrome browser when graphic styles are added to. In Muse Preview tab & Firefox it works and images are shown.

Comment: Could be Chrome's broken implementation of transform-origin I guess.

Comment: I read something about changing the metadata in the <head> from <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">  to <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8"> but not sure what is the problem arose from, and how to change it in Muse